# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content-nav a').on('click',function(){
      var str = $(this).attr("href");   
      var the_id = str.substr(1);
        $("#container").animate({ scrollTop: $(the_id).offset().top }, 1000);
    });
});
```

When I click the link i'm getting error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 which is loaded from google api.

Comment: This question could probably have been answered with a look at the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: My guess is you have a hash and you chopped off the "#" and you actually needed it. But since you did not show what the link looked like it is a guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `the_id` is an id, then you need

```
$('#'+the_id).offset().top
```